# AutoMapper - Map not found

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper in C# and dotNET, to convert Entities to DTO and vice versa, but I keep getting the same error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
UserDTO -> User
FindYourTeam.BusinessLayer.Models.Users.UserDTO -> FindYourTeam.DataAccessLayer.Entities.User
at lambda_method78(Closure, Object, EventType, ResolutionContext)

I get this error with every map I try to do, not just the User, so think its not the fact that is missing the map for this specific type, but most likely something I did wrong to install the package maybe(?)

This is the User Entiy:

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } = new byte[0];
    [Required]
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } = new byte[0];
    public Usertype Usertype { get; set; } = Usertype.User;
    public Details Details { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } = new byte[0];
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } = new byte[0];
    public Usertype Usertype { get; set; } = Usertype.User;
    public DetailsDTO DetailsDTO { get; set; }
}
```

So I have the entity, and the DTO that is quite the same (just without ID), I created a class to Map DTO:

```
CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
CreateMap<UserDTO, User>();
```

I wrote this in the class that implement the Profile Interface. What am I doing wrong? To map inject into the constructor IMapper and create a new instance:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
```

And assign _mapper = mapper in the constructor, then I try to convert in this way:

```
User user = _mapper.Map<User>(userdto);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Of course I have the service.AddAutoMapper in the Startup. I have installed the package needed as well.

Comment: What is `userdto` type?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Are you able to automap DetailsDTO to Details in the same way? It could be failing under that.